# Добавить значения в массив python

Tags: python, sql-server

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выводятся данные в таком виде и нужно каждый элемент через запятую в массив.
Код ниже.

```
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM  БТИ""")
        results=cursor.fetchall()
        #print(results)
        mas=[]
        for row in results:
            print(" ".join(str(row).split()))
```

Comment: А вы посмотрите, что у вас в `row`, там же наверняка именно этот массив уже и есть.

Comment: есть, но я не могу сгруппировать данные в массив

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй это

```
results = "ваш поток ввода".strip('(').strip(')').split(', ')
```

Comment: не работает надо как-то разбить данные в круглых скобках, на подмассивы в квадратных